# Checked and Unchecked value of checkbox get submitted to controller

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I have this form with 14 checkboxes, some may be checked and the user is free to uncheck them as needed.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<h3>New Courses</h3>
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $ns_dataProvider,
'summary' => "{totalCount} courses",
'columns' => [
    [
        'label'=>'Register',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value'=>function ($data) use($student, $active_session_semester) {
           // return Html::a(Html::encode("Register"),'site/index');
            $studentsubject = \app\models\Studentsubject::find()->where([
                'student_id' => $student->id,
                'subject_id' => $data->id,
                'level_id' => $student->current_level_id,
                'session_semester_id' => $active_session_semester->id,
            ])->all();
            $countstudentsubject = count($studentsubject);


            if ($countstudentsubject > 0) {
            return Html::checkbox('subject_id[]',true,['uncheck'=>"r".$data->id,'value'=>$data->id]);}
            else {
                return Html::checkbox('subject_id[]', false, ['uncheck'=>"r".$data->id,'value' => $data->id]);
            }
        },
    ],

    'subject_title',

   ],
    ]); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

I retrieved the value of the checkbox like this

```
 if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $x = Yii::$app->request->Post();
        $subject_ids = $x['subject_id'];
        var_dump($subject_ids);
  }
```

However i get this as the array with 16 values returned instead of 14:

```
   array (size=16)
    0 => string 'r273' (length=4)
    1 => string '273' (length=3)
    2 => string 'r274' (length=4)
    3 => string '274' (length=3)
    4 => string 'r275' (length=4)
    5 => string 'r295' (length=4)
    6 => string 'r296' (length=4)
    7 => string 'r297' (length=4)
    8 => string 'r423' (length=4)
    9 => string 'r424' (length=4)
    10 => string 'r425' (length=4)
    11 => string 'r590' (length=4)
    12 => string 'r591' (length=4)
    13 => string 'r592' (length=4)
    14 => string 'r593' (length=4)
   15 => string 'r594' (length=4)
```

When i check a checkbox, both the checked and unchecked values are sent. Am i missing something? Am fairly new to yii2. Any advice, suggestions and solutions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your model there is a check box with 16 values and the submit return all of them, the fact these are checked or uncheck don'means they don't be submitted. This is not a Yii2  problem.This is normal behavior for the POST submit method

Comment: My form only has 14 checkboxes. Array[0] and array[1] is coming from one checkbox. and Array[2] and array[3] is coming from a second checkbox. thats why the array count is 16 not 14

Comment: I want to submit checked value if the checkbox is checked and uncheck value if it is not. Any idea how i can do this in yii?

Comment: You simply can't. The HTTP POST (the method used foirm subimit)  provide the full submitting of all the data in the model. and for the check box this mean all the values of it. You need manage the data submitted in controllor before saving.

Comment: If this is  useful for you please rate  it